# R Matching function between two matrices

Tags: r, matrix

Sorry if this has been posted before. I looked for the answer both on Google and Stackoverflow and couldn't find a solution.

Right now I have two matrices of data in R. I am trying to loop through each row in the matrix, and find the row in the other matrix that is most similar by some distance metric (for now least squared). I figured out one method but it is O(n^2) which is prohibitive for my data.

I think this might be similar to some dictionary learning techniques but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Both matrices are just 30 by n matrices with a number at each entry.

```
distance.fun=function(mat1,mat2){   
  match=c()  
  for (i in 1:nrow(mat1)){  

    if (all(is.na(mat1[i,]))==FALSE){  
    dist=c()  

    for (j in 1:nrow(mat2)){  
      dist[j]=sum((mat1[i,]-mat2[j,])^2)  
      match[i]=which(min(dist) %in% dist)  
    }  
    }  
  }  
  return(match)  
}
```

Comment: Could you post what you have tried?

Comment: This question could benefit from a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) showing sample input data that is representative of your actual data as well as the desired output. But if you want to minimize distance between two matrixes with `n` rows the number of distances you will have to create is on the order of `O(n^2)`. That doesn't seem avoidable unless you want to change your matching criteria. if you need help with statistical methods, try [stats.se] instead.

Comment: @bencripps Here is a really simple version of what I have right now. It is imperfect because I wanted to check if there might be a less expensive way before fine tuning it.

Answer (score 0):

A better strategy would be to compute the distance matrix all at once first, then extract the mins. Here's an example using simualted data

```
set.seed(15)
mat1<-matrix(runif(2*25), ncol=2)
mat2<-matrix(runif(2*25), ncol=2)
```

and here's a helper function that can calculate the distances between values in one matrix to another. It uses the built in `dist` function but it does do unnecessary within-group comparisons that we eventually have to filter out, still it may be better performing overall.

```
distab<-function(m1, m2) {
    stopifnot(ncol(m1)==ncol(m2))
    m<-as.matrix(dist(rbind(m1, m2)))[1:nrow(m1), -(1:nrow(m1))]
    rownames(m)<-rownames(m1)
    colnames(m)<-rownames(m2)
    m
}

mydist<-distab(mat1, mat2)
```

now that we have the between-group distances, we just need to minimize the matches.

```
best <- apply(mydist, 2, which.min)
rr <- cbind(m1.row=seq.int(nrow(mat1)), best.m2.row = best)
head(rr)   #just print a few

#      m1.row best.m2.row
# [1,]      1           1
# [2,]      2          14
# [3,]      3           7
# [4,]      4           3
# [5,]      5          23
# [6,]      6          15
```

note that with a strategy like this (we well as with your original implementation) it is possible for multiple rows from `mat1` to match to the same row in `mat2` and some rows in `mat2` to be unmatched to `mat1`.